# Windows 10 Pro Sharing/Samba Speed Throttling?

Tags: linux, windows, samba, file-sharing

Does Windows 10 Pro file sharing (aka Samba) throttle its speed?  Mine seems to cap out at exactly 25 megabytes per second.

My Windows 10 Pro machine is directly connected (via crossover cable) to a CentOS samba server with 10gbe (10-gigabit) network cards.

I get at least 7 gigabits per second between the machines.  I tested this by doing an FTP from the Windows box's RAM drive to the CentOS server's RAM drive, I get 899 Megabytes/second transfer (which is about 7.5 gigabits per second).  So I know they can communicate at that speed.

When I connect to the same drives via Windows File Sharing (Samba), it maxes out at exactly 25 Megabytes/second.  That's a rounded number, which makes me think I'm hitting some throttle somewhere, either on the Windows side or the Samba server side.

Samba version: samba-3.6.23-35.el6_8.x86_64

I should also note, Samba appears to use far more server CPU than the FTP server does.

Comment: I don't have the equipment handy to test it out but I suggest you set up a third server to answer your own question.  Make sure you test the throughput in both directions to clarify the rules.

Comment: Are you using 4 wires on your crossover cable to get a full duplex connection or have you negotiated a half duplex connection?

Comment: It's just a a regular copper 10gbe cable, which all 10gbe cables do auto-crossover built-in to the cable, from what I read. Does half-duplex exist in 10gbe (10 gigabit) ethernet? According to the Wikipedia page, only full-duplex exists for all 10gbe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Gigabit_Ethernet Also I doubt it's a network connectivity issue because like I said, I can FTP between the machines and achieve over 7 gigabit transfer speeds..However doing Samba (windows file sharing) between the those machines' RAM drives, only about 200 megabits per second.

Comment: Mine is just at 4.65 Megabit/s.